# Wordpress function when file is uploaded, deleted or edited

Tags: php, uploads, images

I need to call this bit of PHP when a file is uploaded, deleted or edited.

$output = shell_exec("bash ./upload.sh"); 
echo $output;

I can't seem to find the right code to execute this when any of the above happen. Examples and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say if the upload is in admin or on the user side. User side is probably via a plugin, so I have no idea what you are using.

Admin side has a number of hooks related to uploads. Some of them are listed below. Many WP hooks have little or no documentation, so you may have to Read the Source®. HTH

```
./wp-app.php:           do_action('wp_create_file_in_uploads', $file); // replicate
./wp-admin/includes/media.php:do_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'media-upload-popup');
./wp-admin/includes/media.php:do_action('admin_print_styles-media-upload-popup');
./wp-admin/includes/media.php:do_action('admin_print_scripts-media-upload-popup');
./wp-admin/includes/media.php:do_action('admin_head-media-upload-popup');
./wp-admin/includes/media.php:do_action('pre-upload-ui');
./wp-admin/includes/media.php:<?php do_action('pre-flash-upload-ui'); ?>
./wp-admin/includes/media.php:<?php do_action('post-flash-upload-ui'); ?>
./wp-admin/includes/media.php:<?php do_action('pre-html-upload-ui'); ?>
./wp-admin/includes/media.php:<?php do_action('post-html-upload-ui', $flash); ?>
./wp-admin/includes/media.php:<?php do_action('post-upload-ui'); ?>
./wp-admin/custom-background.php:               do_action('wp_create_file_in_uploads', $file, $id); // For replication
./wp-admin/upload.php:<?php do_action('restrict_manage_posts'); ?>
./wp-admin/custom-header.php:                   do_action('wp_create_file_in_uploads', $file, $id); // For replication
./wp-admin/media-upload.php:            do_action("media_upload_$type");
./wp-admin/media-upload.php:            do_action("media_upload_$tab");
```

Comment: The script runs on the server.. it's a upload.sh script that runs commands to upload to amazon S3 using s3sync.

Comment: I had it working in just a .php file that if I loaded it would call the script and echo the results into the browser (what files were uploaded/deleted) but I can't seem to find a hook that would trigger the script after a file is changed.. as it is now I'm having to manually run the script. I could setup a cron job but it seems like a waste of LISTs. I would rather just run it when something needs to get upload/deleted. I was surprised how easy it was to rewrite the urls for S3.. I made a plugin with like 5 lines of code that loads all of my uploads from S3.

Comment: If anyone is interested.. here is the plugin for rewriting the image URLs. <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Rewrite
Plugin URI: http://SudoWorks.com
Description: Rewrites your image paths so that you can use a CDN. 
Version: 2.4
Author: SudoWorks
Author URI: http://SudoWorks.com/
*/

function rewrite_url($rewrite)
{
$rewrite = str_replace('yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/', 'media.yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/', $rewrite);
return $rewrite;
}

add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', 'rewrite_url');

?> Just set a S3 bucket of media.yoursite.com and point a cname at amazonaws.com. done.

Answer (score 2):

Using the **wp_generate_attachment_metadata** filter seems to work OK:

```
function my_after_upload($metadata, $attachment_id) {
    // Your code here
}
add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'my_after_upload', 10, 2 );
```